# Azure Data Explorer, Kusto: regex not semantically correct in extract()

Tags: regex, substring, extract, azure-data-explorer

I am trying to grab a substring of a column value in Kusto.

I know that the string is always preceded by the format 'text-for-fun-' then the string of letters I want, followed by anything that is not a letter.

I thought I should use `extract()` as that allows me to enter a regular expression to handle the multiple possibilities of characters that can follow the string I want.

However, when I attempt to enter the regex, I keep getting a `SEM0420: Semantic error: Regex pattern is ill formed`.

Can you help me figure out how to enter the regex properly?

Example string: `stuff milk-cow-cocoa a/123`

Desired substring: `cocoa`

Current regex: `(?<=milk-cow-\s*).*?(?=\s*[^A-Za-z])`

**Note**: looks like the single asterisks are being removed. They appear below in code.

At this point, the `\s` are to defensively parse the string and remove whitespaces. The end of the overall string may also exist immediately after the desired substring.

I have tried something similar to this Data Explorer statement:

```
cluster("mine").database("mine").
DataTable
| where PreciseTimeStamp >ago(5h) and resourceProvider == "Provider" 
| where info has "cow-milk-"
| take 200
| project extract("(?<=milk-cow-\\s*).*?(?=\\s*[^A-Za-z])", 0, info), info
```

I had to add an extra `\` before each `\` for the Data Explorer to parse the strings correctly.

Comment: Try `| project extract("milk-cow-\\s*(\\S+)", 1, info)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  , That is close, however it fails when there is not a space after the word 'cocoa'. There could be a space, or a digit, or a symbol such as '/'. In those cases, this will fail and return a larger string.

Comment: So, you want to match letters only? `| project extract("milk-cow-\\s*([a-zA-Z]+)", 1, info)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex engine chokes on a lookbehind, and possibly on lookahead, too.

You have a second argument to `extract` that tells the function to return the capture only, so you may use

```
| project extract("milk-cow-\\s*([a-zA-Z]+)", 1, info)
```

It means

- `milk-cow-` - match `milk-cow-`
- `\s*` - match 0 or more whitespaces
- `([a-zA-Z]+)` - match and capture into Group 1 only one or more ASCII letters.